# Landscape OpenID-Connect (OIDC) with ADFS 2019

Tags: landscape

Have installed Landscape on premise release 19.10 and configured openid connect as described on https://docs.ubuntu.com/landscape/en/onprem-auth with ADFS 2019 as Authorization Server / Identity Provider (IdP).
I am able to authenticate against ADFS but I am being redirected to default landscape page with the error: "Ubuntu Single Sign On authentication failed."
Has anyone managed to configure similiar approach and get it working?
How does user mapping work in this scenario?
Other useful information is welcomed!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify, did you use the setup for **OpenID** Support or **OpenID-Connect** Support section of the document?

These 2 options are completely different (as per https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/44611/difference-between-oauth-openid-and-openid-connect-in-very-simple-term ) and for your setup, with ADFS2019 you want to use **OpenID-Connect** Support

Comment: I have used OpenID-Connect which is supported by ADFS. I have followed the guide as described in the Ubuntu documentation. One thing I do not understand is the last part of the openid guide: " Most providers return obfuscated subject identifiers which are not easily available. For this reason, we do not provide a user migration method and recommend than re-creating users." where it is written about re-creating users. Do they mean to mapp in any way current ADFS users or re-create new ones to match ADFS users? If so how to re-create or map users as the only option of login is openid connect.